# I feel left out of a decision - should I contact the project manager?

Tags: communication, colleagues, team, team-role

I am part of a team on a project that is about to start in the next few weeks. While I was away on vacation, a colleague of mine was appointed to the role of Scrum Master.

I felt bad when I came to know of this, because I wanted to be there when this decision was taken.

I don't have a problem with the decision itself, but I can't help but feel "left out". Should I voice this to my project manager? Or is this too much of a non issue?

Comment: And if you were there when he was assigned how would that be different?  If they wanted to assign you to the role of scrum master they would have just waited for you to return from vacation.

Comment: It's clear that they didn't want to assign me to this role, and this is fine by me, that's not what I am asking.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by asking why you were left out of the decision?

Comment: So you are fine with the decision but just upset it was made when you were not there?  If you were assigned scrum master would you also be upset because the decision was made when you were out?  What makes you thinks you should have been part of decision even if you were at the office?  You don't think the project manger had a say in that decision?

Comment: I would expect that the others in the team would be. I am sure the project manager had a say in it, and if so, it would be stupid to challenge it.
@dyeje thanks for the question. I want to not be excluded from future decisions.

Comment: There are many decisions above your pay grade that you will not be included in.  Scum master is not necessarily a decision made by peers.   Excluded is a strong word.   Was this a team meeting in which everyone got input but you were excluded by nature of being out of the office?

Comment: I still don't know (came back last week but the rest of the team was not in the office).

Comment: @Paparazzi "Scum master"?? :)

Answer (score 8):

> Should I voice this to my project manager? Or is this too much of a non issue?

It's a non issue, firstly they're don't have to ask you even if you're not on vacation, secondly you're not unhappy with the outcome, and lastly there is no way to turn back time.

Pick your battles wisely.

Answer (score 1):

This role often rotates among members of the team, so you are probably overreacting. Think of it as an opportunity to watch someone else make the beginner mistakes....

Comment: I think you are mistaken, this role usually, and in our case, won't rotate.
Other than that, making beginner mistakes is something positive.